# Is sparrow framework compatible with iOS 3.0?

Tags: ios, sparrow-framework

I am new to iOS development. I want to build a simple game with sparrow or cocos2d (whichever of these i find more useful). I want to know that whether sparrow framework is compatible with iOS 3.0. I wanted it so that the game also works on iPhone 1. I also want my game to work in iPAD. Lastly which one of these would be more useful to develop simple 2D games on iPhone- Cocos2D or Sparrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparrow Framework has a System Requirement for at least iOS 3.0 which must mean it supports iOS 3.0 which works on the iPhone. It also says it runs on all hardware generations which includes the iPhone 1.

Source: http://www.sparrow-framework.org/info/features/

Comment: For 2D game development on iPhone which one of these would be better in the long run....sparrow or Cocos2D?

Comment: It depends what you want to be honest. Cocos2D has a very large community base which is good if you get stuck and need help and is under very active development.